# what's a PGP passphrase key, in the context of mongo-spark-connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

Can we use mongo-spark connector on spark standalone 2.2.0 and mongoDB 3.4? 
I followed steps on https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark

On trying:
 $ ./sbt +publish-signed

It asks for a PGP passphrase key, leaving it empty does not work.

A similar question is in the following link: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-140
but it doesn't have an answer to this.

Comment: I followed steps in github pages: if you ask, maybe you had some problems. Can you add some details about, please?

Comment: The publish command should be used when someone wants to publish their jar externally, they should mention this in their github repo.

Comment: I have updated the readme to clarify.  Thanks @awisha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to build the packages. Please download them by following the [downloading](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark#downloading) instructions.